# What are the Spring Hibernate Integration jars really required

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I haven't yet found an answer to this question which is bugging me for long. I am trying to integrate Hibernate (3.6.7) with Spring (1.2.8). In order to do so i have to get a bunch of jars just to get it running. Isn't there a more cleaner of way of getting this done. The jars i am using rather forced to use are as below:

- spring-1.2.8.jar
- commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
- hibernate-3.6.7.jar
- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
- dom4j-1.6.1.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar
- javassist-3.12.0.GA.jar

Is there no leaner way? The big list of dependent jars could potentially cause conflict during deployment to my appserver in the future. So its making me rethink about spring-hibernate integration. Is there a way to reduce this dependency list. My issue is not related to management of jars as maven is already being used, it more to do with the usage.

Comment: First of all, this is Java, so probably not. Secondly, your question is basically "How can I use this code without adding it as a dependancy?".

Comment: Oh I read this as, I have a bunch of jars and I want to manage them more effectively. Perhaps my answer isn't that helpful!

Comment: @Alex: I was being facetious. I think your answer addresses the point well.

Comment: @RC. dont ask why..? my hands are shakled..

Comment: i do not think spring 1.2.8. compatible with hibernate 3.6.7.

Comment: @pablochan I was agreeing with you! On second reading it does seem to more of a complaint about using lots of jars than a question about managing them!

Answer (score 3):

This answer was posted before the OP mentioned that he was using Maven. The question seems to be asking how he can use code without including it in his project. Given that there is no answer to that question I'll answer assuming he wants a better way of managing the dependencies that he needs.

The leaner way to do this is to use a dependency management tool such as maven. This allows you to define your project's dependencies in an xml file.

The dependencies you specify will also have dependencies and so on. These are transient dependencies and are very hard to manage without an automated tool.

This is also the best way to ensure that you only have the jars you require.

The dependencies you require are:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: what about hb 3.6.10.Final? which is better?

Comment: The OP said 3.6.7 so I went with that. 3.6.10. I've upgraded now :)